# C# Convert pdf to txt

Tags: c#, .net

I warmly welcome...
I have a question I'm trying to convert PDF to txt and I can not save a txt file ?? Someone please help me ??

```c#
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using System.IO;

namespace ZestawienieFaktur
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }



        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\\faktury\\", "*.pdf");

           foreach (string fp in filePaths)
            {
                ExtractTextFromPdf(fp);
            }

        }

        public static string ExtractTextFromPdf(string path)
        {
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path))
            {
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));
                }

                string lines = text.ToString();
                using (var file = new StreamWriter(@"D:\faktury\test1.txt"))
                {
                    file.WriteLine(lines);
                    file.Close();
                }


            }




        }

    }
}
```

In the folder I have a few pdf files with different names. 
And I want all converted to the format of txt.
Big thx for answer...

Comment: Just put the "return text.ToString();" line which is in between of the function ExtractTextFromPdf() to the end of the function.

Comment: Please edit your question.  In the current Form it's not clear which library you're using

Comment: You have a `return` in the middle of `ExtractTextFromPdf`. Assume that the next lines are not going to be reached

Comment: @ArthurP.R. using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using System.IO;

Comment: @Pikoh Which next line would that be exactly?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen sorry, i don't understand what you mean

Comment: OK, never mind, OP is continously editing the question, this is a moving target. There apparently was a return statement in an earlier version of the code in the question, then there was only an unnecessary but not harming either return statement present, now even that is gone.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen yes now i understand. Yes, when my comment was made there was a return statment in the middle ot the method :)

Comment: I agree. I saw the question early enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `return` keyword instead and just return `void`. The reason why it's not executing is because it stops executing the rest of the code after `return`. Change it to this:

```
public static void ExtractTextFromPdf(string path)
{
    using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path))
    {
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));
        }
        string lines = "";
       using(var file = new StreamWriter(path2))
       {
          file.WriteLine(lines);
          file.Close();
       }      

    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

OK WORKS thx friends...

```c#
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using System.IO;

namespace ZestawienieFaktur
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }



        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\faktury\", "*.pdf");

           foreach (string fp in filePaths)
            {
                ExtractTextFromPdf(fp);
            }

        }

        public static string ExtractTextFromPdf(string path)
        {
            using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path))
            {
                StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

                for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    text.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));
                }

                string lines = text.ToString();
                using (var file = new StreamWriter(@"D:\faktury\test1.txt"))
                {
                    file.WriteLine(lines);
                    file.Close();
                }
                return lines; 
            }


        }




    }

    }
```